# How to express when a child takes too many mouthfuls at once?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

People should not take too many mouthfuls at once and should chew thoroughly each of the mouthfuls one at a time.

It may be harmful to your guts if you don't do that.

My child don't often do that.

**What is the idiomatic way to express it?**

Do you say "**please chew this mouthful thoroughly before taking another one**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way I've heard this expressed (in my American English experience) is "don't gulp your food."

> **gulp**, *transitive verb*
>
> 1 : to swallow hurriedly or greedily or in one swallow
>   [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gulp)

In fact, one of the example sentences provided by Merriam-Webster has this exact usage:

> She told him not to *gulp* his food.